# arabic letters with numpers python

Tags: python, arabic, fpdf, arabic-support, pyfpdf

```
for i in t.split('\n'):                
    arabic_string = arabic_reshaper.reshape(i)
    arabic_string = arabic_string[::-1]
    w = pdf.get_string_width(arabic_string) + 6
    pdf.cell(w, 9, arabic_string, 0, 1, 'C', 0)
```

the problem is that numpers in the var t is flipt too
like 48 -> 84
I need a soloution pls

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking and what the code should do. Please, see [ask].

Comment: @يوشع *arabic_reshaper* converts Arabic block codepoints to Arabic Presentation Forms. This is only a partial solution you also have to use it with *python-bidi* which converts to visual ordering. It will correctly handle Arabic characters without changing the digits. ALternatively, instead of using  *python-bidi* AND *arabic_reshaper*, it is possible to use *pyfribidi* A python wrapper for the Fribidi library which implements the Unicode Bidi algorithm and provides a logical to visual method.

Comment: Do not use `arabic_word[::-1]`this is what is reversing your number instead use python-bidi package.

Comment: `arabic_string = arabic_reshaper.reshape(i)` then `arabic_string = get_display(arabic_string)` then continue building the pdf.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych for those familiar with using Arabic strings in Python it is clear, although it does need editing to more clearly express the problem. He is attempting a hack to get Arabic to display in environments that don't support bidirectional text. 

Firstly by converting the Arabic characters to their presentation forms, then converting the string from logical order to visual order. A crude approximation to this step is to reverse the string. But when you have mixed direction runs in the same string, this screws up the LTR component, so numbers are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue by splitting the string into words, checking if each word is numeric, and reversing only non-numeric parts

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

    def reverse_arabic_string_with_numbers(t):
        reversed_lines = []
        for line in t.split('\n'):
            words = line.split()
            reversed_words = []
            for word in words:
                if word.isnumeric():
                    reversed_words.append(word)
                else:
                    arabic_word = arabic_reshaper.reshape(word)
                    arabic_word = arabic_word[::-1]
                    arabic_word_display = get_display(arabic_word)
                    reversed_words.append(arabic_word_display)
            reversed_lines.append(' '.join(reversed_words))
        return '\n'.join(reversed_lines)

#usage:
t = "مرحبا 48"
reversed_text = reverse_arabic_string_with_numbers(t)
```

Comment: Reading through  your code, it first splits string, then converts Arabic block characters into Arabic Presentation block characters, then reversed the characters in the word, then does a logical to visual conversion (i.e. a more complex way of reversing the reversal). For a console with bidi support, this would ne the same as `print(t)` in a bidi supported terminal. in a non-bidi terminal, It will be reversed. For a terminal with bidi support you'd just use `t` as is.

Comment: There are two conditions: console/terminal has bidi support; console/terminal does not have bidi support. If bidi support just use `line`, don't need *arabic_reshaper* and *python-bidi*. If no bidi support just use `get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(line))`. Alternatively use *pyfribidi* instead of *arabic_reshaper* and *python-bidi*.  It should not be necessary to split numbers and arabic strings, nor should it be necessay to reverse string.

Comment: For instance on macOS, if I use iTerm2 which has no bidi support, your code renders reversed, because of the double reversal. If I use your code on the inbuilt macOS terminal, which has some bidi support) it displays ok.  It displays well because you have reversed string then converted from logical to visual, ie a double reversal of the Arabic part of the text.